# Is nikah without sex though with foreplays valid or void?

Tags: nikah, sexuality

Salam 
 My name is Salman Malik I am from Multan doing a good job.
married 3 years back this was a love marriage but I am suffering from sex phobia that's way I am unable to have sex with my wife and reality is that my all medical reports are OK and I am a true straight sexual person but due to sex phobia i am still virgin .I use to sleep hug kiss for-play after-play everything we do except sex.

Now the thing is that my wife don't want to live with me and she is saying that our Nikah (marriage) is not valid now 
and she left me kindly tell me is that true.

Comment: What's your meaning of the word "true" at the end of your text. you should explain it in a way which this question relate to this site.

Comment: can you explain,what do you mean by sex phobia? it is like ED, PE or just fear to get into sexual acts,or lack of any sexual desire?

Answer (score 3):

**As far as I searched for you inquiry, I didn’t find a related matter that your Nikah (marriage) is invalid. But I found a related issue which could be profitable for you.
According to Islamic rules, this is the duty of men to supply the sexual needs of their wives. According to Islamic rules, such men (who do not..) are sinner, and in accordance with the law, the wives have this right to refer to the court to divorce in the case that this behavior of the men caused difficulty and sin.**

Besides, you’d better to refer to a good psychologist to solve your problem. And you’d better not to allow devil to make you such feelings. Therefore you should trust Allah and say Besmellahe-Rahmane-Rahim and start a good relation with your life.

There is a nice tradition from Imam Ali (a.s.) that could be so profitable for you to read and practice it that declares:

> Whenever you are afraid of something, put yourself on it (logical
>   things), that occasionally fearing that thing is more significant than
>   outer reality. (Hekmat 175 Nahjol Balaqah).

Actually this tradition declares that you should do whatever you are afraid of. (about rational matters). So I reckon your matter is similar to that hadith. In truth, as I said, you’d better trust Allah and ignore your phobia and don’t allow Satan destroy your life.

---

**Reference**:

- [hozekosar.mihanblog.com](http://hozekosar.mihanblog.com/post/46)